# How to get the attribute from html string in php

Tags: php, html

i have to get the attribute from string which contains html code. i'm using string parser to get the attribute but it is not working. 
is there any way to get attribute from the string if the string having html code? for example...

```
$code ="<i class='fa fa-facebook' style='font-size:40px'></i>";
```

result expected as or get attribute value like...

**fa fa-facebook** and **font-size:40px**

i tried to parse it but it doesn't worked.

thank you! in advance... :)

Comment: Show what you tried. That way we can help you through it instead of just making it for you.

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use SimpleXml for this:

```
$code ="<i class='fa fa-facebook' style='font-size:40px'></i>";
$xmlEl = simplexml_load_string($code);
// echo $xmlEl->attributes()->{'class'};
// echo $xmlEl->attributes()->{'style'};
```

Comment: thank you very much @brevis, it worked..